# Is there a way to define a changeType for an onChange event trigger in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, onchange, changetype

I have an inventory spreadsheet with a function that copies and renames an Order Template to create a new Order sheet when you click a button. The function then renames the sheet to the name for the order. Additionally, I have another function, `updateSheetList()`, that copies all the Order sheet names and populates a column which is used with data validation to create drop down menu within a cell on the sheet.

Currently, I have a button on the sheet to update this list for the drop down menu. I would like to automate this so that when a new order sheet is either added through the copy/rename function or deleted manually, it runs the `updateSheetList()` function automatically.

The current code that I have to do this is below:

```
function onChange(e){
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID' || e.changeType == 'REMOVE_GRID'){
    updateSheetList();
  }
```

The trigger works when a sheet is deleted but does not work when I use the copy/rename function. I have realized that the `INSERT_GRID` changeType only works when a sheet is manually created and not when it is duplicated.

So is there a way to either create a custom changeType so that the `onChange()` function triggers when a sheet is duplicated? Is there an alternative workaround to get this to work without using the `onChange()` trigger?

Comment: For that your going to have to talk to Google. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: The duplicate answer provided did not solve my problem but I did figure out the workaround. I just needed to insert updateSheetList() into my button call so that once the new sheet is created, the sheet list is updated automatically.